# Branch coverage for std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx}

Tags: c++, code-coverage, mutex

I couldn't figure out how to test all branches of the following code. In the gtest coverage, it shows that unique_lock declaration and initialization has two branches but I don't know how to test it.
Can you help with this?

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx};
```

I was expecting this declaration wouldn't have two branches.

Comment: If this is the `std::unique_lock` commonly used by g++, the constructor will directly call `lock()`.  And that function has an error branch if there is no mutex and another error branch if it is already locked.  Neither would apply to this constructor, but the logic is still there.

Comment: I understand, but do you have any idea about how to test it? Why is it even shown in branch coverage since it's the internal construct of object.

Comment: It is tested because you can also design objects and want to test their internals.  Try testing the two scenarios that I described in my earlier comment.